# Why I cannot find all the data on a table using selenium

Tags: python, selenium

Sorry, I am a very rudimentary coder. In trying to scrape a website using Selenium, after repeated tries, I am unable to access an element in a table on the website. Is there something that I am doing wrong, and how do I fix it. Thanks!

```
a = driver.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME,'sgx-table-row')

combined=[]

for num in range(len(a)):
    combined.append([])
counter=0
for item in a:

    ticker = item.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME,'a')
    name = item.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME,'sgx-table-cell-text')
    price1 = item.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME,'sgx-table-cell-number')
    
    for item in ticker:
        if len(item.text) != 0:
            combined[counter].append(item.text)
        else:
            pass
    for item in name:
        if len(item.text) !=0:
           
            combined[counter].append(item.text)
        else:
            pass
    for item in price1:
        if len(item.text) != 0:
            
            combined[counter].append(item.text)
        else:
            pass
    counter+=1

   
df = pd.DataFrame(combined)
print(df)
```

The problem is that the result does not return data for all rows in the table. After a certain point, the find_elements method returns empty strings. I am thinking this is because the page only loads the rows that are visible. Hence if I have to scroll to access the other data but I am not sure how to do it.

```
0   N518100E 230201  CMHS   99.000      99  0.827   98.173     ﹣     ﹣     0   
1   N519100A 240201  LSHS   97.000      97  0.945   96.055     ﹣     ﹣     0   
2   N520100A 251101  QGES        ﹣       ﹣  0.111        ﹣     ﹣     ﹣     0   
3   N521100V 261101  IRRS        ﹣       ﹣      0        ﹣     ﹣     ﹣     0   
4   NA12100N 420401  PH1S  110.000     110  0.842  109.158     ﹣     ﹣     0   
5   NA16100H 460301  BJGS  108.000     108  1.069  106.931     ﹣     ﹣     0   
6   NA20100F 500301  ZL8S  108.000     108  0.729  107.271     ﹣     ﹣     0   
7   NA21200W 511001  ZFGS   87.000      87      0       87     ﹣     ﹣     0   
8   NX13100H 230701  R1MS  101.500   101.5  0.157  101.343     ﹣     ﹣     0   
9   NX15100Z 250601  AFUS   99.701  99.701  0.331    99.37     ﹣     ﹣     0   
10  NX16100F 260601  BJHS  102.000     102  0.296  101.704     ﹣     ﹣     0   
11  NX18100A 280501  CMGS   90.000      90  0.585   89.415     ﹣     ﹣     0   
12  NX21100N 310701  RXYS        ﹣       ﹣  0.093        ﹣     ﹣     ﹣     0   
13  NY07100X 220901  7PMS  101.380  101.38  1.214  100.166     ﹣     ﹣     0   
14             None  None     None    None   None     None  None  None  None   
15             None  None     None    None   None     None  None  None  None   
16             None  None     None    None   None     None  None  None  None   
17             None  None     None    None   None     None  None  None  None   
18             Non
```

Comment: Do you need the list of a ll the tags `sgx-table-row`

Comment: Because `search.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME,"sgx-table-row")` does gives me all the tags, put EC wait until the page-container is loaded fully

Comment: Thanks ! I managed to access the element. However I now cannot append it to a list or save it to a csv file. I don't know why but when I use csv.write to a list from the csv li library, the list returns a bunch of empty strings. How may I resolve this ?

Comment: I've updated the question and code

Comment: Where r u getting the error exactly

Comment: Not an error, but beyond a certain point, the data gotten is either None or empty, even though the HTML code remains the same